# Search button in DataGridView. Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a Windows Form with a DataGridView which is binded to an SQLServer. I want to do a button to set the focus on the row that have an specific Id. The Id is given in a text box.

The idea of filtering doesn't solve my problem as I need the number of the row an not the Id.
The DataGridView have two hundred thousand rows. I'm not sure of the idea of checking every row in a loop.

How can i get the IndexRow of a DataGridViewRow which have an specific value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to setup a private BindingSource in the form then set a DataTable loaded from SQL-Server as the DataSource of the BindingSource followed by using the BindingSource as the DataSource for the DataGridView.

Using a TextBox (below its named IdentifierTextBox), place a button on the form with the following code to use the BindingSource Find method to get the position, if -1 is the result the id was not located else the return value from the Find method will be the row index in the DataGridView so we can then set the row via Position property of the BindingSource.

```
private void FindByIdentifierButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(IdentifierTextBox.Text, out var identifierToFind))
    {
        var indexRow = _customerBindingSource.Find("Id", identifierToFind);
        if (indexRow > -1)
        {
            _customerBindingSource.Position = indexRow;
        }
        else
        {
            // failed to find id
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // value in TextBox is not a valid int
    }

}
```

Note with this many records it will most likely still take time but less time then working againsts rows in the DataGridView. It's always better to work againsts a BindingSource rather than querying against the actual DataGridView.